# How to determine the angle of intersection? (2 circles)

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Here's an example of what I have:

[image]

The radius of both circles is 50. Each circle is moved in by 10, so the distance between the two center points is 80.

As you can see one of the circles end at 90 degrees and one ends at 270 degrees.

How can I figure out what degree the 2 lines intersect on, that way I know when to cut off the lines?

Here's how my code looks, just incase it's of any help:

```
c.beginPath();
c.arc(160,250,50,0,(Math.PI/180)*-225,true);
c.lineTo(200,350);
c.lineTo(260,300);
c.arc(240,250,50,(Math.PI/180)*45,(Math.PI/180)*180,true);
c.stroke();
```

The arcs work like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc

Comment: So you want to find the tangent point when the circles intersect at $(40,y)$ after circle radius $50$...  Do you know how to find out what angle that will be?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out at what angle in the circle to stop the line at. So the left circle stops at 90 degrees right now. The answer is somewhere between 0 and 45 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ y=\cos^{-1}(40/50)\approx36.8698976458\deg\approx0.643501108793\operatorname{rad} $$
This is a 3-4-5 triangle, so $ x=30 $

Answer (score 3):

Draw a right triangle with vertices at the center of one circle, the intersection point of the circles, and the midpoint directly between the two centers. That's a 30-40-50 right triangle. From there you have the angles from the definitions of sine and cosine.

Comment: The midpoint between the two circles can't be part of that $30-40-50$...

Comment: Why not? Points at (0,0), (40, 0), (40, 30)?

Comment: Hey, sorry it's been so long - I'm super rusty with my math. So first we solve for X, then for Y? What formulas are we using for both?

And Y will be the answer I was looking for?

Comment: What is Y in your picture?

Comment: Sorry for all of the confusion. The circle on the left currently cuts off at 90 degrees. I know to prevent the line from going too far it needs to stop at somewhere between 0 and 45 degrees. I want to understand how to get that exact value with what I have.

Comment: I added the code I'm working with. It actually draws the line starting at 0 on the x axis. So the right most portion of the circle and goes anti clockwise.

Comment: Okay, so your first arc should start at $\theta = \cos^{-1}(40/50)$ (which is the bottom left angle in that triangle) instead of 0. The second arc should end at $180 - \theta$.

Comment: My mistake, I mixed up the intended triangle.